# Matlab sigma sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, matlab

I'm trying to plot this complicated graph using Matlab.

[image: Image of complicated graph]

I've used 10 instead of Inf but the code doesn't work. Could you please teach me how to fix the sigma sum part?
The error says:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'n'.

Error in @(x)((-0.07305.*x.^5+2.813.*x.^4-39.78.*x.^3+249.5.*x.^2-640.5.*x+1073).*cos(n*pi.*x/6)./6)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 87)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

```
a = @(x) ((-0.07305.*x.^5+2.813.*x.^4-39.78.*x.^3+249.5.*x.^2-640.5.*x+1073).*cos(n*pi.*x/6)./6);
b = @(x) ((-0.07305.*x.^5+2.813.*x.^4-39.78.*x.^3+249.5.*x.^2-640.5.*x+1073).*sin(n*pi.*x/6)./6);
c = integral(a,-6,6)
d = integral(b,-6,6)
e = c.*cos(n*pi.*x./6)+d.*sin(n*pi.*x./6)
g_symsum = symsum(e,n,1,10)+4796.1296
plot(x,g)
```

Comment: This seems like a question for https://www.mathworks.com/

Comment: @DavidRaveh Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using $n$ without defining it first. Rather do something like

```
syms x n
a(x) =  (-0.07305.*x.^5+2.813.*x.^4-39.78.*x.^3+249.5.*x.^2-640.5.*x+1073).*cos(n*pi.*x/6)./6;
b(x) =  (-0.07305.*x.^5+2.813.*x.^4-39.78.*x.^3+249.5.*x.^2-640.5.*x+1073).*sin(n*pi.*x/6)./6;
c = int(a,x,-6,6);
d = int(b,x,-6,6);
e = c.*cos(n*pi.*x./6)+d.*sin(n*pi.*x./6);
g_symsum = symsum(e,n,1,10)+4796.1296;
fplot(x,g_symsum)
```

Comment: Hello, why does the graph only show from x=-5 to x=5?? Your code helps me a lot, but I couldn't see the entire graph.

Comment: @Jay Change the range of plot by using fplot(x,g_symsum,[ -20 20])  or use any range you like

Comment: Thank you so much!!